# Select specific row in oracle without subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a really complex query where I need some call logs as well each to be shown in single row for particular Consignment, so the idea behind is

```
ConsignmentID OTHERCOLUMN OTHERCOLUMN CALL_LOG1             CALL_LOG2
```

now the problem is I can do this using subquery but my call log columns can't accept subquery within subquery to get the specific log #2 and #3

my table structure

```
CALL_LOG
CONSIGNMENTID CALL_LOGID REMARKS
```

Problem occurs in my subquery when I have a where clause on CONSIGNMENT.CONSIGNMENT_ID which is not recognizable for this subquery

```
SELECT CONSIGNMENT_ID, ( SELECT REMAKS FROM (   SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DayRangeId ASC) AS rownumber  FROM CALL_LOG WHERE CALL_LOG.CONSIGNMENT_ID = CONSIGNMENT.CONSIGNMENT_ID  )  as temptablename WHERE rownumber = 4 ) as CALL_LOG1,( SELECT REMAKS FROM (   SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DayRangeId ASC) AS rownumberFROM CALL_LOG WHERE 
CALL_LOG.CONSIGNMENT_ID = CONSIGNMENT.CONSIGNMENT_ID  )  as temptablename WHERE rownumber = 3 )  FROM CONSIGNMENT
```

Comment: Your question is explicitly about Oracle so I removed the other tags.  Also, you should edit your question with sample data and desired results.  The intent of the query that doesn't work is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that field DayRangeId is in call_log table. This query worked for me:

```
with remarks as (
  SELECT CONSIGNMENT_ID cid, remarks,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by CONSIGNMENT_ID ORDER BY DayRangeId ASC) AS rn  
    FROM CALL_LOG )
SELECT CONSIGNMENT_ID, r4.remarks call_log4, r3.remarks call_log3
  FROM CONSIGNMENT c
    left join remarks r3 on r3.cid = consignment_id and r3.rn=3
    left join remarks r4 on r4.cid = consignment_id and r4.rn=4
```